# Using node.js in Visual Studio - 'require' not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

In order to do some pretty big caching, one of my colleagues has recommended that I look at using map-cache (https://www.npmjs.com/package/map-cache).

Now, I've downloaded and installed it. However, in my js file, I try to initially call it using

```
var MapCache = require('map-cache');
var mapCache = new MapCache();
```

This brings up the following:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Looked this up, and apparently I can't use 'require' in this context. People seem to recommend Browserify (http://browserify.org/). Download and install this, and bundle Map-Cache into it. Then, in my cshtml file (I've got a cshtml and a js) I use the following:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Where bundle.js is my bundled script which includes Map-Cache.

Yet it doesn't seem to be working, and still brings up the 'require is not defined' error. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why you are using this in the browser. It seems to be a module used in server side to cache key/value pair and you can't cache in user's machine from the browser. You should have to use cookie/localStorage/sessionStorage to do this.

Comment: The values I'm saving are far too big for cookie/localStorage/sessionStorage (talking of 5-10mb per request), and to be honest this is the one recommended to me by the guy who wrote a lot of it. If there's a better way I'm all for it.

Comment: Just check with him whether he used this in server side or in the browser. If you are using nodejs in your server, then you can use this there. Caching 5-10mb in user's machine is not recommended thats why `cookie/localStorage/sessionStorage` are not supporting them.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Think I'll give it a miss as, because of the nature of the data, it would have to be cached on the user's machine (if we were to cache), but the size of it would pretty much blow out the cache quick enough to be nigh-on useless.